# Is it advisable to keep the model itself in independent application?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I m working with django for a small project. I am not sure if the below approach is a best approach.

I have three applications under a project

1) app1, app2, app3

**Question:**

2) All three applications work with the same model,  and  is it fine if i keep model itself into different application so that app1, app2, app3 can access it?

ie: 1) modelStore, app1, app2, app3.

Kindly consider it is fresher question!!.

Comment: maybe you can post the model and apps names, so we can figure out what is the best place to put you model in.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is you put your model inside the app, which is the most relevant. Then just import it like

```
from app1.models import MyModel
```

this line will work anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not planning on creating a (standalone) reusable app, it's fine to share functionality across those apps.

However you should always consider if splitting up functionality into different apps is really the best solution if the usage is bound close together.

A different approach could be to have just one app, splitting out forms, admins or models (if that improves readability).

```
/project_root
    /project
        __init__.py
        settings.py
    /app
        __init__.py  # imports Foo and Bar from foo_models and bar_models
        /models
            foo_models.py  # requires a `class Meta: app_label = 'app'`
            bar_models.py  # requires a `class Meta: app_label = 'app'`
        /forms
            foo_forms.py
     manage.py
```

And really, just be consistent whatever you pick, there's nothing worse than inconsistent coding.